# Postgresql first password?

Tags: postgresql

Hello i have just installe PostgreSQL 10.7 on Windows.
In the installation it does not asked me to create an user and a password, just installed.

SO i'm trying to login, for exemple with

```
pasql or psql -U postgres
```

and it asks a password but i don't know which password can be.
i tried the defaults like, 1234, postgres, but nothing.
I have tried to insert in the pg_conf the line:

```
host all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust
```

but nothing, it continues to ask a password.

I have tried with the PIn of my windows login but nothing (i have no password, only a PIN).

How can i do?

Comment: You are using a local connection, but your pg_hba.conf accept trust connection for all from remote connection. 

So you have to add your IP 127.0.0.1 in the PSQL command

Comment: Which operating system you are using?

Comment: @PhxDev i tried also with 127.0.0.1 or localhost or nothing, it does not work anyway

Comment: @srimaln91 windows 10

Comment: Try like that : `psql -U postgres postgres` or the same with your IP

Comment: @PhxDev tried....after typing that i ask or "password for user postgres: "

Comment: pg_hba changes requires service restart.

Comment: @Simba yes yes i restarted the services at each change of the file

Comment: Ok ! Did you restart your cluster instance ? I think you have changed your pg_hab.conf file, but you have to restart the instance after.

Comment: @Romans :  use "local all all    trust"   in pg_hba, restart service and then try again. Make it first uncommented line in pg_hba.

Comment: @Simba with local when i restart the server, it gives error on connection and it stops the service

Answer (score -1):

PostgreSQL comes with the Ident authentication system. So you can use below command to access to the database(Only in Linux based operating systems).

```sh
sudo -u postgres psql
```

In windows please try below command

```sh
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -d postgres
```

Comment: Not applicable, as the OP runs on Windows

Comment: i know that, but i have problem in windows, not in linux

Comment: I have edited the answer. Look if you can get something out of that.

Comment: i already tried that @srimaln91 but it asks for a password that i does not know